# List out all values from a mongo array in node

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I'm using MongoDb, Node.js with Express and Jade. I'm trying to list specific objects from a MongoDb array.

Here is what I have so far:

```
app.get('/addsite', function(req, res){
db.sites.find(function(err, docs) {
if (!err)
  res.render('addsite', {
title: 'Add site',
mysites: docs
 });
 else
  res.render('addsite', {
title: 'Add site',
mysites: 'Nothing to see here'
});
 });
});
```

I then try to read this in my Express template using jade with the following:

```
- for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
                li= mysites.url
```

If I set the mysites: docs[0] then it will print out a single url, but I'm trying to grab all of the urls from the objects in the array.

I know this is fairly entry level, but I'm just getting started and this is currently a stumbling block for me.

Appreciate any help/direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul
  each site in mysites
    li= site.url
```